# How to resolve the "Error: WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions is not defined"?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, postback, click

I have an application that is working fine at my local end but when I host it on server, not a single button's click fires. I am getting the Following error:

> Error: WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions is not defined

I don't understand why I am getting this error as I updated the bin folder Ajax dll and I have  installed framework 4.0 on the server but still iI am getting that error.

I have already tried the following link: [WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3933642/webform-dopostbackwithoptions-is-not-defined)

Comment: do you have Javascript errors on that page ?

Comment: Use a debugger from the browser to gather more information. Example: From IE, press F12 to open the debugger. In the debugger window, click the Console tab. What does it show there? Click the Script tab. To the left of the Start/Stop Debugging button is a dropdown of all script files for the page. Does it show a WebResource.axd item? If you select that item, does it show the proper code?

Comment: @AntonioBakula yes i got javascripts error i have pasted already it in question.

Comment: Yea, I saw that, but is there any other Javascript errors, before that "not defined" error ?

Comment: Some times i got "sys is not defined."

Answer (score 1):

i had this problem before, i also did installed everything fresh , but still faced the error and that was abnormally fixed by setting the time on the server. thats bit stupid, but it worked in my case.