# Issue to run javascript in webview with Android version 4.0.3

Tags: android, android-webview, android-version

I'm doing some stuffs. I got unbelievable issue with Webview. I am not able to run javascript with webview in android version 4.0.3. I'm calling webpage that contains java script. I am able to run that with all the version remaining 4.0.3. Is it global issue with this particular version or I'm doing something wrong?

Here is my code:

```
mMainWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.MainWebView);
mMainWebView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64)    AppleWebKit/534.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/13.0.766.0 Safari/534.36");
mMainWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mMainWebView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
mMainWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(
            false);
mMainWebView.setWebChromeClient(new MyWebChromeClient());
mMainWebView.loadUrl("http://mypage.aspx?Go=Go&IMEI=11111111&MAC=00:00:00:00:00:00");
```

My Javascript at webpage:

```
javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions("ctl11", "", false, "", "http://mypage.com", false, true))
```

Please help me with your best suggestions.

Thanks,

Comment: Are you having trouble injecting Javascript or are you saying that the Javascript on the page you are loading into your WebView is not working or something?

Comment: @MarkLyons : JavaScript on the page I am loading into webview is not working with 4.0.3 only. With all other version it's working fine.

Comment: Can you show the JS you're loading in and how?

Comment: @MarkLyons : Of course, Just a sec let me edit my question with code.

Comment: Make sure your javascript doesnt contain newlines and also escape the quotes correctly.

Comment: @MarkLyons : I have update my code here.

Comment: @KiranKumar : Hi, Thanks something interesting. Can you explain me in brief?

Comment: @KiranKumar : How can I verified that?

Comment: Say you are passing "javascript:alert('\nmessage');" in your loadURL, it will give you a javascript exception

Comment: Can you show us the contents of the url that you are loading ?

Comment: @KiranKumar : Hi i have updated my url that I have passed with loadurl. And It is opening dashboard of my webpage.It has contents like webpage only.

Comment: @KiranKumar : I have updated code with my javascript that I'm using at webpage.

Comment: Are you sure that the problem you are facing is not related to this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11516824/how-to-reslove-the-error-webform-dopostbackwithoptions-is-not-defined