# 'WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions is not definded

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, postback, linkbutton

I´m getting an error on IE10 when I postback a form using the LinkButton

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lbSubmit" runat="server" CssClass="regular_btn"
                    onclick="lbSubmit_Click">
                    OK
                </asp:LinkButton>
```

The error: SCRIPT5009: 'WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions is not definded.

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: it is possible for dublicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3933642/webform-dopostbackwithoptions-is-not-defined

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11516824/how-to-reslove-the-error-webform-dopostbackwithoptions-is-not-defined

Answer (score 0):

I installed the Hotfix : http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2600088 and the error disappear

Thanks

Comment: My web server has .net 4.5 and hence it is not allowing me to install the hotfix. Any other alternative to this hotfix available?